# How do I repeatedly send an AT command to a Bluetooth module arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, at-command

I've been working on a project and want an Arduino uno with an HM-19 Bluetooth module to repeatedly send an AT command to the module then print the modules result in the serial monitor.  I'm having trouble and it is only returning the number 53 and not the response 'OK'. Thanks for any insight you're able to give.

```
  //import Software Serial to communicate over comms port
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

  // 0 and 1 are the tx and rx pins ans should be where the hm-19 is
  // may be 0,1 instead
SoftwareSerial HM19(1,0);

void setup() {
  // begin serial monitor and wait for something(?, found online)
Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  //tell user it's started
Serial.println("Started");

  //I believe this begins the monitor for the HM-19
HM19.begin(9600);
delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  // give user status report

delay(1000);
Serial.println("Sending an AT command...");
  // need to find if this is how you send an AT command (currenty send 'AT' as a test)
HM19.write("AT\r");
delay(30);

 //wait for the HM19 to respond then print it out
int HMresponse = 0;
if (HM19.available()){}
  HMresponse = HM19.read();
  Serial.println(HMresponse);
}
```

Comment: Depending on the type of Arduino, Pins 0 / 1 might not be available for SoftwareSerial

Comment: read returns a single char. If you do print with an int variable, you will get its decimal value. 53 is the character '5', not very realistic, if you expect a response like "OK\n" .

Comment: `if (HM19.available()){}`  does not have any effect at all.

Comment: @datafiddler how would I ask for a whole response such as "OK\n".  How do I wait for the HM-19 to respond instead of if (HM19.available()){}

Comment: e. g. via `readBytesUntil()`  https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadbytesuntil/